# Folland Proposition 1.13 Real Analysis, Second Edition

Tags: measure-theory

Proposition 1.13 (b) states: If $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(X)\to [0,\infty]$ by:

$$\mu^*(E)=\text{inf}\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(A_j):\ A_j\in\mathcal{A},\ E\subset\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right\}$$

Then every set in $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mu^*$-measurable (i.e. $A\in\mathcal{A}$ is $\mu$-measurable iff for each $E\subset X$, $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^C)$).

I've managed to follow the proof up to a certain point. Let $A\in\mathcal{A}$, $E\subset X$, and let $\epsilon>0$.

Case: $\mu^*(E)=\infty$, done.

Case: $\mu^*(E)<+\infty$

In this case, there exists a sequence of sets $B_n\in\mathcal{A}$, $E\subset\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$, such that $\mu^*(E)\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n)<\mu^*(E)+\epsilon$.

I then managed to show that:

$$E\cap A\subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\cap A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(B_n\cap A),$$

which implies that:

$$\begin{align*}
\mu^*(E\cap A)
&\le \mu^*\left(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(B_n\cap A)\right)\\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(B_n\cap A)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n\cap A)
\end{align*}
$$

The last line is driven by the fact that $\mu^*\bigg|_{\mathcal{A}}=\mu_0$, which is part (a) of the same proposition. Similarly, I also showed that:

$$\mu^*(E\cap A^C)\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n\cap A^C).$$

But then Dr. Folland writes:

$$\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^C)\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n\cap A)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n\cap A^C)\le \mu^*(E)+E$$

It's that very last inequality where I am stuck. I can see that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n\cap A)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n\cap A^C)\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n)$$

But that's not gonna be less than or equal to $\mu^*(E)+\epsilon$. Am I missing something here, or is there an error in this proof?

Answer (score 2):

Aha! Dr. Folland sent me a good hint (thanks).

First $B_n$ is a disjoint union:

$$B_n=(B_n\cap A)\cup (B_n\cap A^C)$$

Hence:

$$\mu_0(B_n)=\mu_0(B_n\cap A)+\mu_0(B_n\cap A^C)$$

Then:

$$\begin{align*}
\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^C)
&\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n\cap A)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n\cap A^C)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\mu_0(B_n\cap A)+\mu_0(B_n\cap A^C)\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_0(B_n)\\
&\le \mu^*(E)+E\\
\end{align*}
$$